# Automatically submit (click) a FORM after 10 (or more) seconds

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I know this question has been posted and answered many times over the years but, though I've searched here for many hours - none of them have worked for me..

I have a simple FORM that asks for answers A B C D etc that I need to be timed to go to the next question automatically..

```
 <FORM onSubmit="return submitForm(this)" action=QuizProgram.pl method=post name='myform' id='myform'>
```

```
$AnswerNumber++;

(usual INPUT fields - ex: <Input TYPE=radio name=Answers value=A>) etc.
<INPUT TYPE=hidden name=AnswerNumber value="$AnswerNumber">
```

```
<input TYPE=submit VALUE=" Enter "></FORM>
```

Thanx for help solving this (what should be) simple issue..
Nick...

Comment: Did you try setTimeout?

Comment: Yes (thanks for the comeback), several ways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use a timeout callback. Note that setting this timeout up can be kind of funky if you aren't used to the asynchronous event loop of JS, you probably want this to be called as soon as the document is ready (deferred script tag or something similar like `.ready()` in jQuery).

ES6 (works in all modern browsers):

```
setTimeout(() => document.getElementById("myform").submit(), 10 * 1000);
```

Pre-ES6 (to support IE 11 or previous):

```
setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById("myform").submit() }, 10 * 1000);
```